# Problem sending E-mail using C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

When I try to send E-mail using C# with gmail's smtp server,I get this error..

**"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure".**

SSL is enabled

Port used is 587

server name used is "Smtp.gmail.com".

username and password is correct

outlook express works fine on the same pc with the same settings

The c# program also works fine in other places...we get this error only in the clients place.

Would appreciate any help..

Thanks

Edit: @Andomar,Where do I find the root certificates in the client? How do I fix this?

@Alnitak,How do I issue starttls using System.Net.Mail library though?

@David,What do I pass as parameter for  "(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)"

Thanks David. I've added those lines. But,I'm still confused about whats going on since this code doesn't have any direct connection with System.Net.Mail as far as my understanding.Hope the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check that the root certificates are in the Client's Trusted Root Authority store.  If this is from a service then adding the root certificates to the Local Machine store may also help.  To get a better grasp of the reason then I have found the following policy helpful...

```
public bool ValidateServerCertificate( object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
// No errors so continue…
if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
       return true;

// I’m just logging it to a label on the page, 
//  this should be stored or logged to the event log at this time. 
lblStuff.Text += string.Format("Certificate error: {0} <BR/>", sslPolicyErrors);

// If the error is a Certificate Chain error then the problem is
// with the certificate chain so we need to investigate the chain 
// status for further info.  Further debug capturing could be done if
// required using the other attributes of the chain.
      if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
      {
       foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
       {
             lblStuff.Text += string.Format("Chain error: {0}: {1} <BR/>", status.Status, status.StatusInformation);
  }
}

// Do not allow this client to communicate 
//with unauthenticated servers.
      return false;
}
```

To add the policy in, use the following, this only needs to be done once for the Application domain.

```
using System.Net;
...
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
new Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
```

You can also use the policy to remove the error altogether but it would be better to fix the problem than do that.

Comment: You don't need to pass anything in the parameters as it is an Event handler.  The underlying framewrok will do that for you.  If you read past the first code block you will see the call for wiring it in.

Comment: I've added this. But,I'm yet to test it practically at the site where the problem exists.

All I need to do is just add these lines? or Is there anything more to do?

Comment: You might want to change it to log to the Event log.  But yes, I developed this snippet when remote diagnosing a certificate problem for a customer.   Of course the problem was the Root CA cert was in the wrong store as @Andomar stated, but this script helped convince them.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the proper root certificates are in the client's store.  And the client's system date is correct.

Comment: Where to check certificates etc? I'm not using any certificates according to my C# code. I've used the classes in System.Net.Mail

Comment: Since it works elsewhere and not the client, I would bet one US dollar that the client does not know about your CA, so you need to install the certificate/CA at the client

Comment: yes I know SSL uses certificates....But I think the System.Net.Mail library handles them...

Comment: How to install certificate at the client?

Comment: How do I install the certificate at the client? how?

Comment: You can check the certificates in Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates.

Comment: How to installing a certificate? Just double-click it.  If you make David's ValidateServerCertificate return true, your client will accept any server certificate (obviously insecure, but works.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `STARTTLS` or assuming that the connection on port 587 is SSL encrypted from the outset?

Google's servers on `smtp.gmail.com` require STARTTLS.

Comment: I'm using System.Net.Mail.
Is there a way to issue STARTTLS using System.Net.Mail?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx suggests that STARTTLS is the default if SmtpClient.EnableSsl == true

Answer (score 0):

Did you set

```
 client.EnableSsl = true;
```

because gmail needs it